# How to apply different theme in eclipse 3.x RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, styles, themes, rcp

I am following these instructions added in this [link](https://toedter.com/2010/08/17/css-theming-for-eclipse-rcp-3-x/). I need to import bundles checkout from *1*. instruction ***path*** : `pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/eclipse/e4/releng` but it gives ***no such repository*** error message.

> 1. Checkout
>      :pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/eclipse/e4/releng
> 2. Import Project Set /releng/org.eclipse.e4.ui.releng/e4.ui.css.psf
> 3. Checkout e4/org.eclipse.e4.ui/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets (see
>      bug 322641)
> 4. Cleanup org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt (see bug 322644)

**Needed Bundles for 3.x Styling**

```
org.apache.batik.css
org.apache.batik.util
org.apache.batik.util.gui
org.apache.batik.xml
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.jface
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.legacy
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme
org.eclipse.e4.ui.examples.css.rcp
org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets
org.w3c.css.sac
org.w3c.dom.smil
org.w3c.dom.svg
```

I could find only [this](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui) git repository that has some bundles which are needed above. Where can I find these bundles? Is that `cvs` path dead?

Comment: The CVS repository died long ago. Eclipse use Git these days - https://git.eclipse.org/c/

Comment: Is there a Git repository where can I find these bundles together above?

Comment: That link seems to be doing things in a very complex way. It should not be necessary to check anything out to play with CSS styling in current Eclipse. Look at an up to date tutorial such as [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html)